# .htaccess - SSL redicect condition for one specific domain not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, server

I have an apache server with multiple websites hosted:

```
main-website.com 
subdomain1.main-website.com    
subdomain2.main-website.com 
another-website1.com 
another-website2.com    
another-website3.com
```

I need to redirect only https://www.main-website.com to https://www.main-website.com

The subdomains and all the other websites don't need a ssl certificate; therefore I want to exclude them from redirection by specifying that only main-website needs to be redirected.

This is my .htaccess syntax (it seems correct having researched a lot on this topoic)

```
#NON-WWW to WWW (whis applies to all domains and subdomains)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect HTTP to HTTPS only for main-website.com:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} main-website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The condition of redirecting main-website.com has been specified, but it does not work! In fact every other domain and subdomain is redirected to HTTPS!!

Do you know where the error could be?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There must be a typo in your question, you want to redirect from https://www.main-website.com to https://www.main-website.com  I will take for granted you wanted to say http://www.main-website.com to https://www.main-website.com

So, your first `RewriteCond-RewriteRule` set rewrites:

```
somesite.com   --->   https://www.somesite.com
```

But notice that you also force https in that rediction.  Therefore any attempt to reach http://somesite.com will go to https://www.somesite.com

It is probably this rule set that is triggered by your other domains.  That first rule should be to rewrite: `non www` to `www`, without forcing https at that point.

Then the next rule set will apply only to your main-website and send it to https.

Answer (score 0):

```
#NON-WWW to WWW (whis applies to all domains and subdomains)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect HTTP to HTTPS only for main-website.com:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} main-website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have updated the first set of instructions. Still, it does not work :(

Comment: Do not do that as an answer, update your post with all relevant data. And stop doing useless false obfuscation, at least use names from RFC2606.